# I can't apply the migrations in Django DB

Tags: django, sqlite

I am Facing a problem with my project, (cant apply the changes on Django DB)

There was an empty field and it didn't set it to Null = TRUE, Blank =True, when I migrated it kept giving me this error message :

'''

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__orders_order.total

'''

I tried to set the values in the cart model to True and then I changed them to False, It didn't solve the problem.

I tried importing the Integrity error, still didn't solve the issue :

'''

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super.save(*args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError:
            self.code = generate_code()
            super.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

'''

Models

'''

```
from django.db import models, IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from utils.generate_code import generate_code
from products.models import Product
from accounts.models import Address
import datetime 


ORDER_STATUS = (
    ('Received', 'Received'),
    ('Processed', 'Processed'),
    ('Shipped', 'Shipped'),
    ('Delivered', 'Delivered')
)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='order_owner', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank = True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=ORDER_STATUS, max_length=12)
    code = models.CharField(default=generate_code, max_length=20,unique=True)
    order_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    delivery_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    delivery_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='delivery_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank = True)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey('Coupon', related_name='order_coupon', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank = True)
    total = models.FloatField(null=True,blank = True)
    total_with_coupon = models.FloatField(null=True,blank = True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super.save(*args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError:
            self.code = generate_code()
            super.save(*args, **kwargs)

class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order_detail', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='orderdetail_product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank=True)
    qauntity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    total = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    


CART_STATUS = (
    ('Inprogress', 'Inprogress'),
    ('Completed', 'Completed'),
)
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='cart_owner', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank = True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=CART_STATUS, max_length=12)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey('Coupon', related_name='cart_coupon', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank = True)
    total_with_coupon = models.FloatField(null = True,blank = True)
    
    @property
    def cart_total(self):
        total =0
        for item in self.cart_detail.all():
            total += item.total
        return round(total,2)
    

class CartDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name='cart_detail', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='cartdetail_product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank=True)
    qauntity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    total = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    
class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date = models.DateField(null = True,blank = True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.FloatField()
    
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    week = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    self.end_date = self.start_date + week
    super(Coupon, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```
I tried to apply the changes on the DB, but migrations couldn't be applied

when running sqlmigrate command for the latest migration:

'''
(src) ➜  src git:(main) ✗ python manage.py sqlmigrate orders 0014 
BEGIN;
--
-- Alter field total on cartdetail
--
CREATE TABLE "new__orders_cartdetail" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "total" real NULL, "qauntity" integer NOT NULL, "order_id" bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES "orders_cart" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "product_id" bigint NULL REFERENCES "products_product" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
INSERT INTO "new__orders_cartdetail" ("id", "qauntity", "order_id", "product_id", "total") SELECT "id", "qauntity", "order_id", "product_id", "total" FROM "orders_cartdetail";
DROP TABLE "orders_cartdetail";
ALTER TABLE "new__orders_cartdetail" RENAME TO "orders_cartdetail";
CREATE INDEX "orders_cartdetail_order_id_091b0028" ON "orders_cartdetail" ("order_id");
CREATE INDEX "orders_cartdetail_product_id_40b59fd6" ON "orders_cartdetail" ("product_id");
--
-- Alter field total on order
--
CREATE TABLE "new__orders_order" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "status" varchar(12) NOT NULL, "code" varchar(20) NOT NULL, "order_time" datetime NOT NULL, "delivery_time" datetime NULL, "total_with_coupon" real NULL, "coupon_id" bigint NULL REFERENCES "orders_coupon" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "delivery_address_id" bigint NULL REFERENCES "accounts_address" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "user_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "total" real NULL);
INSERT INTO "new__orders_order" ("id", "status", "code", "order_time", "delivery_time", "total_with_coupon", "coupon_id", "delivery_address_id", "user_id", "total") SELECT "id", "status", "code", "order_time", "delivery_time", "total_with_coupon", "coupon_id", "delivery_address_id", "user_id", "total" FROM "orders_order";
DROP TABLE "orders_order";
ALTER TABLE "new__orders_order" RENAME TO "orders_order";
CREATE INDEX "orders_order_coupon_id_5bddb887" ON "orders_order" ("coupon_id");
CREATE INDEX "orders_order_delivery_address_id_6ecfdbf4" ON "orders_order" ("delivery_address_id");
CREATE INDEX "orders_order_user_id_e9b59eb1" ON "orders_order" ("user_id");
--
-- Alter field total on orderdetail
--
CREATE TABLE "new__orders_orderdetail" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "qauntity" integer NOT NULL, "price" real NOT NULL, "order_id" bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES "orders_order" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "product_id" bigint NULL REFERENCES "products_product" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED, "total" real NULL);
INSERT INTO "new__orders_orderdetail" ("id", "qauntity", "price", "order_id", "product_id", "total") SELECT "id", "qauntity", "price", "order_id", "product_id", "total" FROM "orders_orderdetail";
DROP TABLE "orders_orderdetail";
ALTER TABLE "new__orders_orderdetail" RENAME TO "orders_orderdetail";
CREATE INDEX "orders_orderdetail_order_id_8d02dd1f" ON "orders_orderdetail" ("order_id");
CREATE INDEX "orders_orderdetail_product_id_3ecd225e" ON "orders_orderdetail" ("product_id");
COMMIT;
```

Comment: did you tried add a default value in the model.   if its not helpful write a django management command/script to fill a valule ( 0 )to the empty field if its null/blank. after running the script, your 'total' column will be filled with 0 for all  rows where its null.  Then run the migration.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.